# How can I install gutters where there is no roof overhang, and the walls are concrete block?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, gutters

I have a detached garage that has a flat rubber roof that slopes from front to back. There is however no overhang at the back of the garage, and no gutters, so water is running down the concrete block walls.

**Question:**  What is the best way to install it? Should I get a piece of pressure treated wood and attach that to the block first, and then attach the gutter to the wood?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; could you add a picture of the area? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: It somewhat depends on how the rubber is terminated at the roof edge. Please provide more detail and/or photos.

Comment: See photo in the original post.

Comment: How is the existing gutter installed?

Comment: It's screwed directly into the concrete block. Is that a good approach? I want to do whatever I can to keep water off that back wall, as water is starting to come inside the garage.

Comment: _"water is starting to come inside the garage"_ -- if the intrusion is new, it may be more worthwhile to investigate a possible maintenance issue with existing drainage, than to add gutters. Is there any draining (french, footing, etc.) along the base of the wall? Have you looked into why water is coming in now, when presumably it did not before?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, this is a new property for me, so I'm unsure how long this has been an issue. The roof was replaced recently (prior to me) but the drainage along the back wall was never addressed. My assumption, after watching a recent rainstorm is water is running down the back wall and getting in some how.

Comment: Water's not likely to travel laterally through a wall when it can fall vertically to the ground. So if water's getting in, it's presumably after it reaches the ground. Often there would be some kind of drainage system along the foundation of the building; assuming the building is slab-on-grade, I'd guess a French drain. If there's is one, maybe it's failed and needs fixing. If there's not one, maybe the best solution is to add one. This all assumes water is coming in at ground level; if it's present higher up, I think it's more likely the roof is leaking.

Comment: All that said, if that ivy has penetrated the stucco, I guess it could be acting as a conduit through the wall as well. You'll want to clean up the wall anyway, so maybe do that first and see if it affects the water intrusion at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Yes, I was planning to clean up all of that ivy when I went to install the gutter- I guess back to my original question of properly installing the gutter. Do you think it's worth getting the water off that wall? If yes, could you offer an idea for installation.

Comment: Is the roof flat and level or is it pitched in a certain direction? If pitched, which direction? Gutters should not be put along a roof line which the roof is not pitched toward. toward.